# How to wrap an H2 and <p> tag in a border like in the image:

Tags: css, border

Is there an easy way to achieve the same design as this image using css on a h2 and p tags?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try below's code.

```css
.box {
  margin-top : 50px; 
  border : 1px solid #000; 
  padding : 15px;
  width : 500px; 
  margin-left : auto; 
  margin-right : auto; 
  position : relative;
}

.title {
  position: absolute; 
  top: -20px; 
  font-size: 24px; 
  background: #fff; 
  padding: 3px 0; 
  width: 300px; 
  text-align: center; 
  left: calc(50% - 150px);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="box">
 <div class="title">&lt;h2&gt;Sample Text&lt;/h2&gt;</div>
 <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to help a stranger! You're a kind man. Works great